# package ia32-lib is not available on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Red http://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html on WSL (I'm using on Windows 10 Pro). After typing

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libc6-i386 libcurl3
```

In the end I got the message

```
ia32-lib has no installation package
```

Does it mean it's not possible ?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions for “the multiarch way” (further down the same page)? Why not just use the Windows version?

Answer (score 3):

The linked page says that you need to do multiarch way if you are on Ubuntu 13.10+

You can easily check your Ubuntu version by running `lsb_release -r` which looks like this on my install:

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    16.04
```

### Installation

1. Add support for the 32-bit architecture:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```
2. Update your `apt` and install the necessary 32-bit C libraries

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libcurl3:i386
   ```
3. Grab the Linux binary

   ```
   $ wget http://static.red-lang.org/dl/linux/red-063
   ```
4. Make the binary executable

   ```
   $ chmod u+x red-0*
   ```
5. Run the installer

   ```
   $ sudo ./red-0*
   ```

Now you should be all good! Just run the binary after setup and it will launch the Red console